# Create a variable from the output of a select statement and use that variable in another select statement POSTGRE SQL

Tags: postgresql

Say I have the following query:

```
SELECT quantity
FROM TABLE A
WHERE account = xx
AND date = xxx-xx-xx
```

this query returns one value. Say I now want to use that value in a second query, as a variable, like:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) + variable as 'CURRENT POS'
FROM TABLE B
WHERE account = xx
AND date = xxx-xx-xx
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tb2 WHERE account = xx AND date = xxx-xx-xx) +
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tb1 WHERE account = xx AND date = xxx-xx-xx)
```

Just note there are a million ways to solve it :-)

Comment: That helped - but now I need to do more things with it. Is there a way to set the result of a first statement to a variable that I can use in other statements?

Comment: You can use an alias `AS variable` to store it. But depending on what you want to do, you will need to write a stored procedure

Comment: example: `select (select 2) as a, (select 2) as b`